# I need advice on calculating this limit of a function resulting in $-\frac14\pi$

Tags: limits, infinity

I am looking for advice on solving this limit of a function.

I am struggling to find the correct process:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\operatorname{arccotg}\frac{x}{(x^2-4)^{\frac12}}$$

Comment: Maybe someone can figure out how to write "arccotg" in LaTex...

Comment: @barakmanos: `\operatorname{arccotg}` is preferable to `\text{arccotg}`, since it leads to proper spacing.

Comment: What do you mean by arccotg? I've never seen it before. Is it just the function $g$ such that $g(1/\tan(x)) = x = 1/\tan(g(x))$?

Comment: Hint: The denominator is $|x|\left(1-\frac{4}{x^2}\right)^{1/2}$.

Comment: @PatrickStevens: Dunno, I just converted OP formula to LaTex...

Comment: It is just another way of writing cot^-1

Comment: :-) but to help OP answer the question: maybe you could use $\arctan y + \operatorname{arccotg} y= \pi/2$.

Comment: Note that there are different definitions of this function,
the sign symmetric function $\mathrm{arccot}(x) = \arctan(1/x),\;x \ne 0\,$ 
and the continous $\mathrm{arccotc}(x) = \pi/2 - \arctan(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\text{arccotg}$ is the inverse function of $\cot$. (I'm using whichever version always outputs within the range $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.)

The $\operatorname{arccotg}$ function is continuous near infinity (and therefore respects limits), so the answer is:

$$\operatorname{arccotg} \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}$$

That limit expression is (by L'Hôpital)

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{1}{1/2 (x^2-4)^{-1/2} 2x} = \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} -\sqrt{1-\frac{4}{x^2}}$$

By continuity of the square root near infinity, that is

$$-\sqrt{\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1-\frac{4}{x^2} \right)} = -1$$

So the entire answer is $\operatorname{arccotg}(-1)$, which by oddness is $-\text{arccotg}(1) = -\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: $\operatorname{arccot}$ is not an odd function like $\arctan$.

Comment: @Bernard It depends on where you set the range to be. I'm using $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, where it does all work out.

Comment: @Bernard I should note that Mathematica uses this branch of arccot. That's the only thing I know about which branch is standard.

Comment: It is not the official definition.

Comment: @Bernard, it is the only one which gives the answer OP is expecting, though.

Answer (score 0):

With equivalents, one sees at once that
$$\frac x{(x^2-4)^{\tfrac12}}\sim_{-\infty}\frac x{\lvert x\rvert}\to -1,$$
hence by continuity,
$$\operatorname{arccot}\frac x{(x^2-4)^{\tfrac12}}\enspace\text{tends to}\enspace\operatorname{arccot}(-1)=\frac{3\pi}4. $$
as the range of $\operatorname{arccot}$ is $(0,\pi)$.